# Making empty a VBA collection

Tags: vba, list, collections, arguments

I have a problem with a Collection object in Visual Basic for Aplications (I use it with Excel)

I have this code trying to empty a Collection object that I have to re-use:

```
Sub limpieza(ByRef listilla As Collection)

    While listilla.Count <> 0
        listilla.Remove (listilla.Count)
    Wend

End Sub
```

But when I call it with:

```
Dim listado As New Collection
<I have some code here that add some values to the collection>
limpieza (listado)
```

VBA says to me that

> argument is not optional

and the code doesn't run.

What can I do? I need to use this collection cleaning at the bottom of a loop that reuses the Collection object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Dim listado As New Collection
<I have some code here that add some values to the collection>
limpieza listado
'this syntax also works
Call limpieza(listado)
```

Note that I removed the `()` around the argument.

When passing `byref` you want to do this as `()` causes VBA to pass it as `byval` by default unless you add `Call` as well.

This can be really frustrating since you can often actually use `subName(args)` as syntax sometimes but run into these sorts of problems. I generally use `Call mySubName(args)` to make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks you solved a lot of problems I had with sub-routines, MSDN documentation is not a very useful source of information. I'm a bit noob with this languaje

Answer (score 30):

If you want to empty a collection, instead of calling a separate procedure, just use

```
Set listado = New Collection
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that there's also doing Set `listado = Nothing` I can make the same. I keep the vote on enderlands answer because it solved more procedure problems o me. See you.